# npx create-next-app@latest is not working and this is the error, How to solve it?

Tags: node.js, npm, registry

everytime i run this "npx create-next-app@latest" on my visual studio, there's an error saying about my "registry". please can somebody help me about this?

npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-next-app failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND host
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

Comment: **This is a low quality post and is unlikely to be salvageable.** All code should be correctly formatted using inline code fences or code blocks, including error output. The title is deformed, uses incorrect grammar and capitalization, as well as the body of the post. Additionally, this error is, in no way, related to `create-next-app` and the error output includes all relevant information to solve this issue. You have not noted what steps you have taken to remediate this issue, as the error output suggests. Please consider these changes, otherwise we may have to remove this post.

Comment: Check your network as the ERROR specifically says.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether your problem is same as mine, but I also got a regitry related problem when excuting `npx next-create-app@latest`

I got error as below

```
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/creat-next-app - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'creat-next-app@latest' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

I solve this problem by deleting the url of mirror for npm packages I set before with command below.

```
npm config delete registry
npm config delete disturl
```